# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to install and import the aux library

Tags: python, pip

I wanyt to do the feature extraction of the images and as part of it want to use the aux library. I have pip installed the aux library and getting an error. I am trying to find a solution for the following error.

```
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/d8/1ca6b67fee40d3fba147853cdce37bae241a0f0b6b9ee0cb2f60473f2f37/aux-0.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=e8f5148d0bdbec8dc64722a64592121835ea99e774b2be89a66384b99ef0df52 (from https://pypi.org/simple/aux/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aux (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.0.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for aux
```

I tried installing it by doing pip install aux == 0.0.2 and it says the following.

```
ERROR: Invalid requirement: '=='
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put **no spaces between** the package name, the `==`, and the version.

```bash
pip install aux==0.0.2
```

Comment: Tired this and still the same error.

Comment: are you _sure_ it's the _same_ error? I made a typo, it's supposed to be `==`, not '='. if you tried my previous answer with just the '=', please try again with `==`.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have tried  pip install aux==0.0.2
following is the error.
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8d/6c/a0607831a2d4f6d4c6069692ceb533cb78e2706202952a98edcd5164a589/aux-0.0.2.tar.gz#sha256=5af8f646622308f141aff51a11dc6b075a097de1b7283675dba73c886ec37515 (from https://pypi.org/simple/aux/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aux==0.0.2 (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.0.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for aux==0.0.2

Comment: then my answer *does* fix the error message you asked about (`ERROR: Invalid requirement: '=='`). -- that new error is an entirely different issue. I don't know why pip has an issue there. try just `pip install aux` without any version.

Comment: This what happening when I run the
pip install aux
Firstly Thank You for responding
WARNING: Discarding files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/d8/… (from pypi.org/simple/aux). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output. ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aux (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.0.2) ERROR: No matching distribution found for aux

Comment: that package hasn't had any activity since 2015! you should contact the author. their email is listed on https://pypi.org/project/aux/

Comment: Yeah saw that it was last updated in the year 2015. I am actually trying for image alignment by feature extraction.
Below is the link where I found this package for feature extraction and matching. Please let me know if you know of a better approach. Thank You.
https://magamig.github.io/posts/accurate-image-alignment-and-registration-using-opencv/